# Dynamically obtaining a data type, but getting a TypeError

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the code:

```
data_type = raw_input("Enter data type")
c = 5 + data_type("4")
print (c)
```

I entered the `data_type` as `int` and it threw an error like this:

```
Enter data typeint
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "qcode.py", line 2, in <module>
    c = 5 + data_type("4")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Basically, I want the user to enter a data type like `int`, `str` and others then use them later

Comment: Any idea what you're trying to do?

Comment: Do you want the user to actually enter a datatype, like `int`, and then later use that datatype as a constructor?

Answer (score 1):

For your case, I would recommend having a dictionary from strings representing the types to the types themselves.

```
recognised_types = {"int": int,
                    "str": str,
                    "float": float}

usr_in = raw_input("Enter the data type> ")
usr_type = recognised_types[usr_in]

print repr(usr_type("4"))
```

This may feel a little repetitive at first, but it does mean you can at least try to predict what will happen, and if the user tries to enter a type you're not supporting, it will fail predictable at the stage where you're trying to decode it, by raising a KeyError. This will be a lot easier to handle and adapt for validation, etc. Here is an example of this in action:

```
Enter the data type> int
4

Enter the data type> str
'4'

Enter the data type> float
4.0

Enter the data type> dict
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 6, in <module>
    usr_type = recognised_types[usr_in]
KeyError: 'dict'
```

Now as you're in Python 2, you could have done:

```
data_type = input("Enter data type")
c = 5 + data_type("4")
print (c)
```

`input` in Python 2 just immediately tries to evaluate the input as a Python expression. However, this is both dangerous and undesirable. This would also have worked fine for the first 3 examples, but for the last example, this would have happened:

```
Enter data typedict
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "naivecode.py", line 2, in <module>
    c = 5 + data_type("4")
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

This error is kind of opaque and difficult to predict, as it happens (could happen) far away from where the input was obtained, so the approach with the lookups is generally going to be a better idea. However, even with Python's duck typing, you might struggle to keep track of all your classes if you can't predict if it will be '`int`, `str`, or other'.